# Searching data from a table using stored procedure in oracle by passing tablename as a parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i, ora-06512, ora-01756

This procedure is not working properly.

```
create or replace procedure bank_search_sp
(
p_tablename in varchar2,
p_searchname in varchar2,
p_bankcode out varchar2,
p_bankname out varchar2,
p_dist_code out number
)
as
v_tem varchar2(5000);
begin
v_tem :='select bankcode,bankname,dist_code from ' || UPPER (p_tablename) || '
where bankname like '''|| p_searchname||'';
execute immediate v_tem into p_bankcode,p_bankname,p_dist_code using p_searchname ;
commit;
end bank_search_sp;
```

the Procedure is getting created but i dont know what actually happens when it was executed ,This is the error shown

```
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
ORA-06512: at "PENSIONS.BANK_SEARCH_SP", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Trailing commas are missing from this line:

```
v_tem :='select bankcode,bankname,dist_code from ' || UPPER (p_tablename) || '
where bankname like '''|| p_searchname||'''';
```

Notice the 4 commas at the end of the string fragment. The first opens the string, the last closes it, the middle two insert a single comma that will be the closing comma for the search expression).

The `UPPER()` function is not necessary; Oracle does not care the casing of the object names.

I am not sure if having multiple tables with the same structure is the best solution. Would not it be better to have one table only with an indexed column indicating the difference between banks?